# Jquery: if link is clicked open pop up and close all current pop up which are open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I managed to create a jQuery command that opens a pop up (`.more-news`). In this page there are several links which open different pop up's. This pop up has a closing button, but if the user clicks on another link which opens another pop up it will overlay each other as shown on the image. To avoid this I want a jQuery command which if you click any link to open a pop up it first closes any other open pop up to avoid this overlay.

Any suggestions?

Post with link to open pop up:

```
<article class="news-thumb">
                        <time>08/07/2013</time>
                        <div class="news-info">
                            <img src="images/news/post-2.jpg" alt="#">
                            <h1>Main title</h1>
                            <p>lorem ipsum su madre. Lorem ipsum su madre. Lorem ipsum... </p>
                            <a href="#" class="more-btn-2">Read more <i class="sprites-more-news"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

pop up code:

```
<article class="more-block-1">
                        <div class="more-news">
                            <h1>Main title</h1>
                            <a href="#" class="pop-link">
                                <i class="sprites-pop-news-close"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="more-text">
                                <p>
                                    Donec a ligula eget dolor ornare adipiscing. Ut varius pulvinar nisi eget feugiat. Sed dictum ante nec pharetra tincidunt. Nulla eget aliquam lacus, vitae ullamcorper lacus. Suspendisse ultricies quis orci in aliquam. Morbi eget elit felis. Etiam consectetur eleifend libero varius lacinia. Proin justo felis, viverra lobortis
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    Donec a ligula eget dolor ornare adipiscing. Ut varius pulvinar nisi eget feugiat. Sed dictum ante nec pharetra tincidunt. Nulla eget aliquam lacus, vitae ullamcorper lacus. Suspendisse ultricies quis orci in aliquam. Morbi eget elit felis. Etiam consectetur eleifend libero varius lacinia. Proin justo felis, viverra lobortis
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

jquery command to fade in the pop up:

All pop up codes have in common class `.more-news`.

```
$(function() {
        $(".more-btn-1").on('click', function() {
            // CODE THAT CLOSES THE REST OF OPEN POP UPS
            $('.more-block-1').fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the popups share the class `.more-news`, you can just hide all the element with that class before you show the current popup.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".more-btn-1").on('click', function() {
        // CODE THAT CLOSES THE REST OF OPEN POP UPS
        $('.more-news').not('.more-block-1').fadeOut();
        $('.more-block-1').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/28f7917d229a359de7ee13557d742843

DRYer example: http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/a0c35556dd938c87159ebac81d141290

Comment: Thats the approach I was thinking about, but the problem I had was that it appeared and disappeared. Until I saw I need to have the class at the same level, so more-btn had to have the class more-new applied to the same article. If it's the child it wont work as the parent element gets hidden. If I have in a future a lot of posts I will have a hell of a jquery code. Is there a better method that won't make the jquery code so infinite?

Comment: What I've done is the following for now. I added jqpost on the same line as .more-block-1, and added the following line inspired with your solution: $(".more-btn-1").on('click', function() {
      $('.jqpost').fadeOut();
         $('.more-block-1').fadeIn('slow');
         return false;
     }); This makes that I don't need to write a different line for each new post.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that doesn't require as much repetition. Now all you have to do is provide the number of the popup in the ``data-popup`` attribute.

Comment: data-popup? this would make me avoid to insert the number on the class? This would be marvelous. This way it would detect the number with another method, and not via the class name. Really smart! I'm I right?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The example DRYer example is exactly what I was searching. didn't think about using the data atribute. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I assumed that all of your pop-ups starts with more-block

```
$(function() {
   $("div[class*='more-block']").on('click', function() {
       var $className = $(this).attr("class");       
       var id = $className.substring($className.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
       $("div[class*='more-block']").hide();
       $('.more-block-' + id).fadeIn('slow');
       return false;       
   });
});
```

Comment: Each post class is called more-block-{number} So each post the first is more-block-1 and the second more-block-2 and so on. Do you know a method which targets only more-block and fades in depending on the number? So it would detect "-1" in this example.

Comment: that what i tryied to do.
catch all classes that start with more-block.
I didn't understand what you asked. what do you mean targets only more-blocks and fades in depending in the number?

Comment: Maybe we are talking about the same thing... So that piece of code means classes beginning with more-block? This would mean that of the class was .more-block-1 the line $("div[class*='more-block']").hide(); would work as the class has more-block string inside the name of the class?

Comment: Yes. the `*` char says that everything that contain the string `more-block`
that it also `more-block-1`, `more-block-2`, `more-block-3` etc..
So for example: it'll will hide all more-blocks and then will fadeIn more-block-1.

Comment: just checked your code and it does not work with my markup. What I meant is the following... to avoid having to create a new function for each new post I would like to know for example, if there is a method to detect the number in the class string so I don't need to add a new class which unifies all the posts all together. Therefore I'm trying to see if there is a method that I could use the same class, in this case .more-block-1, so I didn;t hae to add a new class only for the jquery. Is this understandable? Maybe I'm not so clear...

Comment: I think that i understand you. You mean get the digit from the class for the element that binded with the "click" event. right?
And then hide all and the specific element fadeIn?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38725/discussion-between-daniel-ramirez-escudero-and-dvir)